# GLFW - Rotating camera's view matrix with mouse makes it spin

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, glfw

I'm using glfw to get the mouse position and then I calculate the offset (or delta as I label it in my code) and I use that to rotate the camera around the x- and y-axes. It all works fine, however, when I make circles with my mouse it makes the camera spin along the z-axis for some reason.

Here's my code where I calculate the x- and y-delta positions of the mouse:

```
void input(Window* window, float deltaTime)
{
    rotationMatY = Matrix44::CreateIdentity();
    rotationMatX = Matrix44::CreateIdentity();
    translationMat = Matrix44::CreateIdentity();

    float oldXPos = (float)mouseX, oldYPos = (float)mouseY;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window->getGLFWWindow(), &mouseX, &mouseY);

    float xDelta, yDelta;
    xDelta = (float)mouseX - oldXPos;
    yDelta = (float)mouseY - oldYPos;

    const float R_SPEED = 10.f;

    // Rotate the camera around with the mouse according to how much it's moved
    // since the last frame
    if (getMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT))
    {
        rotationMatY =
            Matrix44::CreateRotateY(DegToRad(R_SPEED * xDelta * deltaTime));
        rotationMatX =
            Matrix44::CreateRotateX(DegToRad(R_SPEED * yDelta * deltaTime));
    }
}
```

I then take the view matrix of the camera and multiply it by the resulting rotation matrices:

```
void Crate_full_framework::onRender()
{
    view *= rotationMatY;
    view *= rotationMatX;

    ... // Other rendering code here
}
```

And here is how I calculate the rotation for the x- and y-axis:

```
Matrix44 Matrix44::CreateRotateX(float angle)
{
    return Matrix44(1.f, 0.f,          0.f,         0.f,
                    0.f, cosf(angle),  sinf(angle), 0.f,
                    0.f, -sinf(angle), cosf(angle), 0.f,
                    0.f, 0.f,          0.f,         1.f);
}

Matrix44 Matrix44::CreateRotateY(float angle)
{
    return Matrix44(cosf(angle), 0.f, -sinf(angle), 0.f,
                    0.f,         1.f, 0.f,          0.f,
                    sinf(angle), 0.f, cosf(angle),  0.f,
                    0.f,         0.f, 0.f,          1.f);
}
```

I'm just stuck in trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with my maths. I'm pretty sure that I have to reset the orientation of the y-axis for the camera so that it's up is always in the positive y direction, just not sure how to get there.

**EDIT:** I uploaded a video to YouTube here: https://youtu.be/2QXKvOGHXgM that just shows what happens when circling the mouse while rotating the camera.

Comment: Without looking for the actual error in your matrix code, just a small remark. I usually wouldn't roll my own matrix/vector code. There are libraries that do this both better and faster (using sse/neon intrinsics).  For example the header only [GLM library](http://glm.g-truc.net) is quite popular and most opengl tutorials actually use this one as their preferred implementation as it tries to closely match the syntax of glsl shaders.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I would really love to use glm but unfortunately this is for school so I have to code it all myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating this thread with my solution as to help people in the future.

The problem was that I wasn't creating a completely brand new transform matrix every frame. I was trying to add to the old view matrix and so that is why the camera would spin. It would take the old up vector and add the new one to it and that would create the spin. So the code is now just this:

```
view = rotationMatTotal * translationMat;
```

Instead of this:

```
view *= rotationMatTotal * translationMat;
```

Thanks for all the replies, they were informative and a I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the video, i see the issue. What you are looking for is a virtual trackball. Stackoverflow provides:

https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-to-implement-a-trackball-in-opengl

What you are currently using looks like euler angles which (among others) have the problems you've just experienced.

from: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/

- Interpolating smoothly between 2 orientations is hard. Naively interpolating the X,Y and Z angles will be ugly.
- Applying several rotations is complicated and unprecise: you have to compute the final rotation matrix, and guess the Euler angles from this matrix
- A well-known problem, the “Gimbal Lock”, will sometimes block your rotations, and other singularities which will flip your model
  upside-down.
- Different angles make the same rotation ( -180° and 180°, for instance )
- It’s a mess - as said above, usually the right order is YZX, but if you also use a library with a different order, you’ll be in trouble.
- Some operations are complicated: for instance, rotation of N degrees around a specific axis.

You could trivially implement it using quaternions the explanation of which is provided in the above source

Comment: I was thinking that it probably had something to do with euler angles. I'll check out the links you provided. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here, but may be you should put whole code under condition `getMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT)`.

```
    void input(Window* window, float deltaTime)
    {
        // Rotate the camera around with the mouse according to how much it's moved
        // since the last frame
        if (getMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT))
        {

          rotationMatY = Matrix44::CreateIdentity();
          rotationMatX = Matrix44::CreateIdentity();
          translationMat = Matrix44::CreateIdentity();

          float oldXPos = (float)mouseX, oldYPos = (float)mouseY;
          glfwGetCursorPos(window->getGLFWWindow(), &mouseX, &mouseY);

          float xDelta, yDelta;
          xDelta = (float)mouseX - oldXPos;
          yDelta = (float)mouseY - oldYPos;

          const float R_SPEED = 10.f;


          rotationMatY =
                Matrix44::CreateRotateY(DegToRad(R_SPEED * xDelta * deltaTime));
          rotationMatX =
                Matrix44::CreateRotateX(DegToRad(R_SPEED * yDelta * deltaTime));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't expect much from it, but it was something new that I hadn't thought of. Tried it, didn't work though. Thanks anyway though.